# Adding Button Controls Inside Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I had this problem, I can't add a control inside a class. More specifically the `Controls.Add(Button);`. Is this possible or do i missing something.

```
    MyFunctions mf = new MyFunctions();
    class MyFunctions
    {
        public int ButtonWidth(int number)
        {
            string a = "";
            int ButtonWidth=0;

            Button x = new Button();
            x.Size = new Size(10, 40);//Initial Size
            x.AutoSize = true;
            x.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            Controls.Add(x);//Why i can't this one?

            for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
            {
                a += "X";
                x.Text = a;
                ButtonWidth = x.Width;

                MessageBox.Show(i + "-" + a + "-" + ButtonWidth);
            }
            return ButtonWidth;
        }
  }`
```

I got an error message.

> can't access a non-static member of outer type.

I made a trial to see if the button width is changing when `button.text` changes its length. but the `button.width` is held constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyFunctions` is a separate class from your `Form` class. And therefore, it does not have `Controls` property (the `Controls` property belongs to your `Form` - or its derived - `class`)

If you want to add a `Button` in your `Form` `class`, you should make your code block a `Method` of your `Form` instead of a new, separated `MyFunctions class`:

```
public class MyForm : Form {  
    public int ButtonWidth(int number) //this is OK
    {
        string a = "";
        int ButtonWidth=0;

        Button x = new Button();
        x.Size = new Size(10, 40);//Initial Size
        x.AutoSize = true;
        x.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        Controls.Add(x);//Why i can't this one?

        for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
        {
            a += "X";
            x.Text = a;
            ButtonWidth = x.Width;

            MessageBox.Show(i + "-" + a + "-" + ButtonWidth);
        }
        return ButtonWidth;
    }
}
```

That being said, since your method name is to `ButtonWidth`, it is not advisable (not a good design) to add `Button` in a method which is meant to get `ButtonWidth`. Consider separation of Methods: `CreateButton` to create your `Button`, `GetButtonWidth` to get the `ButtonWidth` (though it may not be necessarily made a method) and then you simply add your created `Button` to your `Form`'s `Controls`.

Comment: @Vincent great. ;) please note my comment on your code design too... I strongly encourage you to consider separation of Methods to make your code becomes much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an instance of a class, from an instance of another class.

Try making `MyFunctions` static, or include the functions on a base class that the first class derives from.